# Is it possible to write a message inside a "Console.ReadLine()"

Tags: c#, console.readline

Is there a way to write a message inside of `Console.ReadLine()`

Like:

```
Console.ReadLine("What is your name: ");
```

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for `Console.WriteLine()` or perhaps `Console.Write()`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, the only way is to write a message before reading a line. Use `Console.Write()` instead of `Console.WriteLine()` to prevent outputting a newline.

```cs
Console.Write("What is your name: ");
string name = Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 5):

There is no way to do exactly what you've asked, but you can write a helper method for this.

Here's a simple example of a method that takes in a string that will be displayed to the user, and returns the string that the user enters:

```
public static string GetStringFromUser(string prompt)
{
    Console.Write(prompt);
    return Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Now this can be used like:

```
string userName = GetStringFromUser("Please enter your name: ");
Console.WriteLine($"Hello, {userName}!");
```

**Output**

[image]

Answer (score 4):

ReadLine is not like a Dialog Box, where you can give the user output, about what input you want.

If you want to tell the user what to do, you need a seperate `Console.WriteLine()` to do so.

```
Console.WriteLine("What is your name: ");
var input = Console.ReadLine();
```